# How to only run certain lines of text file through dictionary and keep everything else the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my Computational Biology final project, I am required to take a DNA sequence, translating it into RNA, and then translate that into a protein structure. Below is an example (2dna.fasta, what is running through my code right now)

```
>ENST00000632684.1
GGGACAGGGGGC
>ENST00000434970.2
CCTTCCTAC
```

Anything that starts with a dash is metadata while everything else is a protein sequence. I could do it so every other lines is translated but for the second part of the final project, the file looks like this

```
>ENST00000651352.1 cds chromosome:GRCh38:3:3126963:3148101:1 gene:ENSG00000072756.17 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay gene_symbol:TRNT1 description:tRNA nucleotidyl transferase 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:17341]
ATGCTGAGGTGCCTGTATCATTGGCACAGGCCAGTGCTGAACCGTAGGTGGAGTAGGCTG
TGCCTTCCGAAGCAGTATCTATTCACAATGAAGTTGCAGTCTCCCGAATTCCAGTCACTT
TTCACAGAAGGACTGAAGAGTCTGACAGAATTATTTGTCAAAGAGAATCACGAATTAAGA
ATAGCAGGAGGAGCAGTGAGGGATTTATTAAATGGAGTAAAGCCTCAGGATATAGATTTT
GCCACCACTGCTACCCCTACTCAAATGAAGGAGATGTTTCAGTCGGCTGGGATTCGGATG
ATAAACAACAGAGGAGAAAAGCACGGAACAATTACTGCCAGGGTTTTGATGGCACTTTAT
TTGACTACTTTAATGGTTATGAAGATTTAA
>ENST00000434583.5 cds chromosome:GRCh38:3:3126965:3150879:1 gene:ENSG00000072756.17 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay gene_symbol:TRNT1 description:tRNA nucleotidyl transferase 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:17341]
```

My original solution was to just remove the lines that started with dash but this would not include the metadata that I need. Is it possible to somehow separate the meta data from the from the dna, run the DNA data through the dictionary, and then put the dna in between the metadata (like where it was before it went through the dictionary).

As stated above, I have tried removing lines that start with '>' but that can only work if I didn't need the meta data. I do need the meta data. I have also tried making it so it only reads lines that start with 'ATG' as majority of the DNA strands star with ATG but for the beginning of the second part of the project, the DNA does not start with ATG for around a 100 lines.

```
import sys
file = open('2dna.fasta' , 'r')

DNASequence = ''
for lines in file.readlines():
    if not (lines.startswith('>')):
        DNASequence = DNASequence +  lines 
    
DNASequence = DNASequence.replace('\n', '')
print('The original DNA sequence is', DNASequence)

CompletmentDict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}
final = ""

for letter in DNASequence:    
    final += CompletmentDict[letter]
    
print ("Your completement is: ", final)

final2 = "" 
    
DNATORNADICT = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}

for letters in final:
    final2 +=  DNATORNADICT[letters]

print("Your Final DNA TO RNA TRANSCRIPTION IS: " + final2)

rna2protein = {'UUU':'F', 'UUC':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
'UCU':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCA':'S', 'UCG':'S',
'UAU':'Y', 'UAC':'Y', 'UAA':'', 'UAG':'',
'UGU':'C', 'UGC':'C', 'UGA':'', 'UGG':'W',
'CUU':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUA':'L', 'CUG':'L',
'CCU':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCA':'P', 'CCG':'P',
'CAU':'H', 'CAC':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
'CGU':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGA':'R', 'CGG':'R',
'AUU':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUA':'I', 'AUG':'M',
'ACU':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACA':'T', 'ACG':'T',
'AAU':'N', 'AAC':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
'AGU':'S', 'AGC':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
'GUU':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUA':'V', 'GUG':'V',
'GCU':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCA':'A', 'GCG':'A',
'GAU':'D', 'GAC':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
'GGU':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGA':'G', 'GGG':'G'}

final3 = ""

for p in range(0,len(final2),3):
    myKey = final2[p:p+3]
    final3 += rna2protein.get(myKey)
    
print("Resulting protein is: ", final3)

proteinSeq = open('proteinSeq.txt', 'w')
proteinSeq.write(final3)
proteinSeq.close()
```

The output of this is

```
The original DNA sequence is GGGACAGGGGGCCCTTCCTAC
Your completement is:  CCCTGTCCCCCGGGAAGGATG
Your Final DNA TO RNA TRANSCRIPTION IS: GGGACAGGGGGCCCUUCCUAC
Resulting protein is:  GTGGPSY
```

and in my results file it looks like

```
GTGGPSY
```

but i want it to be like

```
>ENST00000632684.1
GTGG
>ENST00000434970.2
PSY
```

How could I do this? If you need any clarification on what any of this means, let me know

Comment: before you write final3 to your document , try to insert a new line . to do this : `proteinSeq.write("\n "+final3)`

Comment: But how do I put Metadata in the empty lines.

Comment: does your file contain many DNA?

Comment: Oh yeah the whole file is 232000 lines long and majority of it is dna

Comment: Btw, do you really need the intermediate steps (competement and RNA) or only the end protein ? Because if it's the last case, you could greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @Swifty yes i do need to complement it and run it through rna. The point of the program is to take the dna, separate it from the meta data (the thing that starts with >) and then run it through the dictionaries. The dictionaries complement it, transcribe it into rna, and then translate that into protein. Then it is supposed to go back to its original spot right under the meta data it was taken out from. This is what I do not know how to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "go back to its original spot". You're reading the file, not modifying it, so the DNA data is till where you got it from. And you don't write the complement and RNA to an output file, only the protein chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want (based on your expected output), this does the job:

- I wrapped the DNA transcoding into a function.
- The main part of the code checks for metadata lines; if found, it transcodes the previous (if any) DNA sequence and writes the protein to file, then writes the metadata line and proceeds to the next DNA block.

```
    def treat_DNA(seq):
        print('The original DNA sequence is', seq)
      
        CompletmentDict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}
        final = ""
        for letter in seq:    
            final += CompletmentDict[letter]  
        print ("Your completement is: ", final)
      
        final2 = ""   
        DNATORNADICT = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}
        for letters in final:
            final2 +=  DNATORNADICT[letters]
        print("Your Final DNA TO RNA TRANSCRIPTION IS: " + final2)
      
        rna2protein = {'UUU':'F', 'UUC':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
        'UCU':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCA':'S', 'UCG':'S',
        'UAU':'Y', 'UAC':'Y', 'UAA':'', 'UAG':'',
        'UGU':'C', 'UGC':'C', 'UGA':'', 'UGG':'W',
        'CUU':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUA':'L', 'CUG':'L',
        'CCU':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCA':'P', 'CCG':'P',
        'CAU':'H', 'CAC':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGU':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGA':'R', 'CGG':'R',
        'AUU':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUA':'I', 'AUG':'M',
        'ACU':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACA':'T', 'ACG':'T',
        'AAU':'N', 'AAC':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGU':'S', 'AGC':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
        'GUU':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUA':'V', 'GUG':'V',
        'GCU':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCA':'A', 'GCG':'A',
        'GAU':'D', 'GAC':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGU':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGA':'G', 'GGG':'G'}
        final3 = ""
        for p in range(0,len(final2),3):
            myKey = final2[p:p+3]
            final3 += rna2protein.get(myKey)
        print("Resulting protein is: ", final3)
      
        with open('proteinSeq.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(final3+'\n')
    
    file = open('2dna.fasta' , 'r')
    
    DNASequence = ''
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if DNASequence:
                treat_DNA(DNASequence)
            DNASequence = ''
            with open('proteinSeq.txt', 'a') as file:
                file.write(line)
        else:
            DNASequence += line.strip() 
    treat_DNA(DNASequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any domain specific knowledge about what you need to accomplish so let me know if I'm misunderstanding anything.

It looks like there is a line of metadata followed by the DNA sequence it relates to. If this is the case, I think it would be helpful to split these into separate entries that you can process sequentially.

Assuming that the > character only appears in front of the metadata lines and nowhere else in the file, you could use this as a delimiter to split the string:

```
my_sequences = []
with open('myfile.txt' , 'r') as file:
  # split along the metadata delimiter
  for entry in file.read().split('>')[1:]:
    # split the entry at the first newline character to separate the metadata and sequence
    [meta, seq] = (entry.split("\n", 1))
    my_sequences.append({"meta":meta, "seq": seq})

with open('proteinSeq.txt', 'w') as proteinSeq:
  for entry in my_sequences:
    DNASequence = entry["seq"].replace("\n", "")
    print('The original DNA sequence is', DNASequence)

    CompletmentDict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}
    final = ""

    for letter in DNASequence:    
        final += CompletmentDict[letter]
    
    print ("Your completement is: ", final)

    final2 = "" 
        
    DNATORNADICT = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}

    for letters in final:
        final2 +=  DNATORNADICT[letters]

    print("Your Final DNA TO RNA TRANSCRIPTION IS: " + final2)

    rna2protein = {'UUU':'F', 'UUC':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
    'UCU':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCA':'S', 'UCG':'S',
    'UAU':'Y', 'UAC':'Y', 'UAA':'', 'UAG':'',
    'UGU':'C', 'UGC':'C', 'UGA':'', 'UGG':'W',
    'CUU':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUA':'L', 'CUG':'L',
    'CCU':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCA':'P', 'CCG':'P',
    'CAU':'H', 'CAC':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGU':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGA':'R', 'CGG':'R',
    'AUU':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUA':'I', 'AUG':'M',
    'ACU':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACA':'T', 'ACG':'T',
    'AAU':'N', 'AAC':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGU':'S', 'AGC':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'GUU':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUA':'V', 'GUG':'V',
    'GCU':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCA':'A', 'GCG':'A',
    'GAU':'D', 'GAC':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGU':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGA':'G', 'GGG':'G'}

    final3 = ""

    for p in range(0,len(final2),3):
        myKey = final2[p:p+3]
        final3 += rna2protein.get(myKey)
        
    print("Resulting protein is: ", final3)
    proteinSeq.write(f""">{entry["meta"]}\n""")
    proteinSeq.write(f"{final3}\n")
  proteinSeq.close()
```

You'll end up with an array of dictionaries that you can loop over where each dictionary has a separate key value pair for the metadata and the following sequence.

Comment: Hey this works but how do i get it so that the sequencing data goes through the dictionary so it gets into a protein and also make it so that it gets outputted into a file?

Comment: You should be able to move most of your existing code into the for loop for the new entries array. I've updated the answer to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

I made some adjustement on your code :

```
import sys
file = open('2dna.fasta' , 'r')
proteinSeq = open('proteinSeq.txt', 'a')

metaData = []
DNAs = []

DNASequence = ''
for lines in file.readlines():
    if not (lines.startswith('>')):
        DNASequence = DNASequence +  lines 
    else:
        DNASequence = DNASequence.replace('\n', '')
        DNAs.append(DNASequence)
        metaData.append(lines.split(" ")[0])
        DNASequence = ""

def showData(metaData,DNASequence):
    print('The original DNA sequence is', DNASequence)

    CompletmentDict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}
    final = ""

    for letter in DNASequence:    
        final += CompletmentDict[letter]
        
    print ("Your completement is: ", final)

    final2 = "" 
        
    DNATORNADICT = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C' : 'G'}

    for letters in final:
        final2 +=  DNATORNADICT[letters]

    print("Your Final DNA TO RNA TRANSCRIPTION IS: " + final2)

    rna2protein = {'UUU':'F', 'UUC':'F', 'UUA':'L', 'UUG':'L',
    'UCU':'S', 'UCC':'S', 'UCA':'S', 'UCG':'S',
    'UAU':'Y', 'UAC':'Y', 'UAA':'', 'UAG':'',
    'UGU':'C', 'UGC':'C', 'UGA':'', 'UGG':'W',
    'CUU':'L', 'CUC':'L', 'CUA':'L', 'CUG':'L',
    'CCU':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCA':'P', 'CCG':'P',
    'CAU':'H', 'CAC':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGU':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGA':'R', 'CGG':'R',
    'AUU':'I', 'AUC':'I', 'AUA':'I', 'AUG':'M',
    'ACU':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACA':'T', 'ACG':'T',
    'AAU':'N', 'AAC':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGU':'S', 'AGC':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'GUU':'V', 'GUC':'V', 'GUA':'V', 'GUG':'V',
    'GCU':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCA':'A', 'GCG':'A',
    'GAU':'D', 'GAC':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGU':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGA':'G', 'GGG':'G'}

    final3 = ""

    for p in range(0,len(final2),3):
        myKey = final2[p:p+3]
        final3 += rna2protein.get(myKey)
        
    print("Resulting protein is: ", final3)
    proteinSeq.write("\n " + metaData + "\n " + final3)

for i in range(len(DNAs)):
    showData(metaData[i],DNAs[i])

proteinSeq.close()
```